# Is there a date format in Spark only for the year or month?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataframe df with a column date_string - which represents a string like "20220331" - the following works perfectly:

```
df = df.withColumn("date",to_date(col("date_string"),"yyyymmdd"))
```

For "20220331" the column "date" of type date - just as required - now looks like this: 2022-03-31

I now want two columns "year" and "month" of type date. For "20220331" the column year should be 2022 and the column month should be 2022-03. The following does not work:

```
df = df.withColumn("year",to_date(col("date_string"),"yyyy")
       .withColumn("month",to_date(col("date_string"),"yyyymm")))
```

Is it even possible in Spark to have something in the form of yyyy and yyyy-mm in the date type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_format`:

```
scala> Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
     | date_format(current_timestamp(),"yyyyMM")
     | ).show
+----------------------------------------+
|date_format(current_timestamp(), yyyyMM)|
+----------------------------------------+
|                                  202203|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Alternatively, if your date is stored as a string, you could just substring the values out.